# Thunderbird: how to get back compact message list

Tags: thunderbird

The lest large Thunderbird update (supernova) brought more spacious design with it. Sadly, now my 2K screen doesn't fit sufficiently many messages anymore, and I'm scrolling the message list all the time.

Is there a way to get the old, compact list view back? (I'm talking one text line per email in a table, ca 14pt text size, as for example in [this old screenshot](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spam.png)).

My research indicates it's not possible via settings or `about:config`, and my work on modifying CSS properties in userChrome.css is both deprecated and leads to UI quirks (scroll position not matching selected mails etc).

What's the proper way of achieving this?

Comment: You can modify display parameters using the `≡` menu : Density and Font Size. Does this help?

Comment: @harrymc huh! Is that new? yes, that works!

Comment: I think it was added in the supernova update, but I may be wrong. I added an answer.

Comment: @harrymc I just checked by rolling back to a pre-supernova version of a fedora machine, then running an update: at the very least the mechanism that profiles coming from older versions of Thunderbird default to compact density is new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify display parameters using the `≡` menu :
Density and Font Size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, definitely more elegant than [my userChrome.css experimentation](https://mastodon.social/@funkylab/111212703159275018)